# Method works when returning integers, but a NoSuchMethodError happens when the same method is asked to return a Double

Tags: java, arrays, methods, runtime-error

ANSWER FOUND: My jdk compiled the files together which caused the error, the fix was to compile each file on its own. I appreciate all the help, thank you!

I have a method that returns an average of the integers in an array. The following method works correctly:

```
public int arrayAvg(int[] nums){
    int result = 0;
    for (int i : nums){
        result = result + i;
    }
    return result/nums.length;
}
```

but when the following method is used in its place:

```
public double arrayAvg(int[] nums){
    double result = 0;
    for (int i : nums){
        result = result + i;
    }
    return result/nums.length;
}
```

the program compiles, but stop here in the code with a `java.lang.NoSuchMethodError`

Comment: Do you have more than one source file? If so, did you recompile the sources that depend on the source you just changed?

Comment: *stop here in the code with a java.lang.NoSuchMethodError* - please post yout stacktrace

Comment: Both code snippets are fine. Are you using reflection to call this function? Beware that using reflection the return code matters, so you might be calling the old function which after the change does not exist anymore

Comment: You are trying to overload a method but both methods contain the same signature even though one returns **int** and the other returns **double**. Change the name of one method to **doubleArrayAvg()**.

Comment: Welcome to to the world of pain separate compilation and changing the contract brings.

Comment: @DevilsHnd according to the post, he changed the method, he didn't overload it

Comment: did you re-compile the class having main() method or the class from where you are calling arrayAvg() ?

Comment: @slaw I do have more than one source file, but I don't understand what you mean by recompiling the sources

Comment: @julodnik I don't understand what you mean by reflection

Comment: @deshi I'm using NetBeans which as far as I understand recompiles the code automatically, no? I did save between attempts though

Comment: I think, it should depends, check if it is set as build automatically. Not sure about net beans. Try to add some print statement in main method and all the place where you are calling these two method. If new print executed then you can be sure that everything required is compiled.

Comment: @deshi I’ll for sure check the build settings, and as for the print statements, I had some set already. The one before the method runs, but the one after doesn’t. It crashes before then

Comment: @THEminotuar Could yo please share java files where you defined thees methods and java files where you are calling these method and the java file containing main method.